Merging rasters using QGIS modeler
Using the QGIS modeler, I want to automate the following sequence:
1: Filter point clouds,
2: Convert each slab obtained into DEM
3: Merge all MNT
with the model below, I only obtain a fusion of a single slab!
Do you have any idea where the problem comes from?

